# Retrieve primary keys of cascade deleted rows

Tags: php, mariadb, primary-key, sql-delete, cascade

Good evening,

following table situation:

```
create table TableA (
pkA int not null auto_increment,
propertyA varchar(20),
primary key (pkA) );

create table TableB (
pkB int not null auto_increment,
pkA int not null, 
propertyB varchar(20),
primary key (pkB),
foreign key (pkA) references TableA (pkA) on delete cascade);

create table TableC (
pkC int not null auto_increment,
pkB int not null, 
propertyC varchar(20),
primary key (pkC),
foreign key (pkB) references TableB (pkB) on delete cascade );
```

When I delete a row from parent table 'TableA' I need to know which rows (primary keys) got deleted in 'TableB' and 'TableC' as well.
I am working with PHP 7.0. I was hoping there is something like mysqli_insert_id for deletes, but... nada :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you just do a simple select with the condition you have first and then delete ?

Comment: That would be a solution, although it requires more work as I have to do several selects to get all primary keys from all tables. I hoped for a simple solution.

Comment: ok, can you give us your delete statement ?

Comment: `delete from TableA where pkA = "<ID>"`. I will retrieve the referenced tables from information_schema.key_column_usage to select the rows first before I delete them.

Comment: Face it, `FOREIGN KEYs` do only a few 'simple' things.  You are asking for something more complex.